# Quorum private transaction is being reverted by EVM

Tags: transactions, quorum, private, constellation

I had setup an quorum network using quorum maker (3 nodes). I tried to perform a public transaction and it worked. But when I tried to perform a private transaction it gets reverted by the EVM

```
node:25206) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Transaction has been reverted by the EVM:
{
  "blockHash": "0xc89a7fc5a1cbd11ce501f8bcc349ab82d1b9f3f9404fe093502603409fb96ac4",
  "blockNumber": 20,
  "contractAddress": null,
  "cumulativeGasUsed": 0,
  "from": "0x59a83f92034da597b815debb45d4e8bd215763ee",
  "gasUsed": 0,
  "logsBloom": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "status": false,
  "to": "0xf315438f4b07fa2948e404610f8de6a69733b6cd",
  "transactionHash": "0x66a9dbc463fd2a4486dd78c6c97d29bb048fbb27d7a739be91f63551f548e225",
  "transactionIndex": 0,
  "events": {}
}
    at /root/Desktop/quorumtest/testproject/node_modules/web3-core-method/src/index.js:364:46
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:25206) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:25206) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Is it because constellation is not working /running properly. Am I missing something here ?

Comment: please post a calling code sample, and check if your private for entries : whether they are correct or not.

Answer (score 1):

Reverted by EVM does not mean an error in Constellation -- 9 out 10 times it means that theres an issue with the code part of the txn. If you show that, I could point out what the issue may be.

Do note that Quorum does not support private value transfers.